# Google Spreadsheet: Sum if column A matches 'X' and column B matches 'Y'

Tags: excel, excel-formula, google-sheets, spreadsheet

Right now, I have the following formulae in a google spreadsheet to give me sum of all the rows where there is "Inflow" in column E. I want to add another column and
criteria in the SUMIF. SUMIF the column F is "Returns":

```
SUMIF(E:E,"Inflow",B:B)
```

Is there a way to do it without writing a macro?

Answer (score 2):

In a google spreadsheet you can use [SUMIFS()](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3238496)

```
=SUMIFS(B:B, E:E,"Inflow", F:F, "Returns")
```